# How to flag an entity when it is created or updated?

Tags: 8, entities, flags

I have a Drupal 8 site with the Flag module.

I want when a user creates or updates a node, product, store, group, ... the updated entity is flagged.

How to flag an entity when it is created or updated ?

I'm testing the "Rules" module which is finally (usable) in production.

But how do you flag down a new entity when it is created ?

What should be put in "Action", because it is no longer like in Drual 7 with an interface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the Rules module?

Comment: Might this be a duplicate of: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-flag-a-node-that-has-just-been-created

Comment: @bleen Yes, but the Rules module seems completely dead, it's been years since there is a stable version and I don't dare install it on my non-production site.

Comment: @bleen Can the "Actions" module do this ?

Comment: @sdiff your statement is completely false and misleading - Rules is extremely active and under development, and is even compatible with D9 and is used by tens of thousands of sites. This posters task is trivial with Rules.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @anonymous Sorry I just retested the rules module and it's still not possible to do such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HOOK_entity_presave to trigger when node gets created. I updated code for you. Make sure that you change the capital letters to correct values.

```
function MODULENAME_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Check which content type would you like to flag.
  // You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php to check for 
  // multiple content types
  if (in_array($entity->bundle(), ['mycontentype1', 'mycontentype2'])) {
    $flag_id = 'yourflagname';
    
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    
    // Flag an entity with a specific flag.
    // https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/introduction-to-entity-api-in-drupal-8
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll try to do this from the Drupal 8 interface.

Comment: I don't know programming very well. I know how to create the base of a module, but what should the module file contain ?

Comment: @sdfff I updated the code for you.

Comment: Thanks, I just created a module with your code, but I have 2 PHP error when I register a node https://ibb.co/2q8YgXp https://ibb.co/fGwxXGx https://ibb.co/4dWRpJr

Comment: is the content already flagged? than maybe need to add another check

Comment: The flag is created but the content is not created

Comment: ok, that means that we need to use a new hook because the entity does not exist yet. Replace presave with MODULENAME_entity_update

Comment: Thanks, it works. If I do the same for groups, stores and prosuit, is it the same code ?

Comment: I updated the answer for easier code reading - use PHP function in_array which accepts two parameters array of machine names of content types and the second parameter actual entity type which we update. You can place your content type machine names in the array

Comment: Thanks, i just tested but i got this error in terminal after doing a drush cr `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www/www-s1biose-com/web/modules/custom/admin_report/admin_report.module on line 5
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.` https://pastebin.com/v5w5ke4Z

Comment: there is one bracket missing for if clause )

Comment: Yes indeed it was missing the closure. I fixed and I still have a PHP error :-( `Message Warning : in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given dans admin_task_notify_entity_update() (/var/www/www-s1biose-com/web/modules/custom/admin_task_notify/admin_task_notify.module ligne 4)`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5LAK3Vh8

Comment: hm, seems like we did a mistake, in_array must first accept the string we searching for for the second parameter you need the array in which you're searching for. my bad. I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working. One last question, if I have to flog several totally different entities, what do I do? I created a flag per type of entity. Here is the complete code that I would like to do: https://pastebin.com/h80nCdbb

Comment: that is the correct way to do it.You can place  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag'); to the first line of the function so you don't have to repeat it all the time

Comment: Ok but there is a problem, how does it tell the difference between the different type of entity. For example between nodes and comments that have the same machine name? Should we put a comma at the end of each IF ?

Comment: If I apply my code, when I post a comment, I have lots of errors in my logs https://ibb.co/ygPfqdh

Comment: I posted my code here https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3170711

Comment: I found a similar module but I don't know what I need to change in mine so that it no longer displays an error
 https://git.drupalcode.org/project/rules_flag/-/tree/1.0.x